# Selenium webdriver and python ERROR: Unsupported command addSelection

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to convert some of my selenium IDE scripts to webdriver/python runs.  We have a page that contains a box with a list of options.  I need to select an option, then click a button that moves this option to a second box.  The IDE command that selects the option I want looks like this:

```
addSelection | id=WholeList | label=first option
```

When I convert this to python, that line gets an ERROR: Unsupported command

Any idea how I can convert this so that python will select the option I want?  The next command, the clicking of the button, converted ok.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `Select` functionality:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("WholeList"))
select.select_by_visible_text("first option")
```

Documentation here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select

Comment: Thanks so much Richard.  This worked perfectly.  I'm still new to python especially and your answer was straightforward and easy to understand.  Ed